# Boto3 IAM User creation failing with InvalidClientTokenId - The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3, amazon-iam

When I do this:

```
session1 = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='my_profile')
iam_client = session1.client('iam')
```

Given that `user='an_existin_iam_user'`, the below succeeds as I can print the accessKeyId and the accessKeySecret successfully.

```
responseCreateAccessKey = iam_client.create_access_key(UserName=user)
accessKeyId = responseCreateAccessKey.get('AccessKey').get('AccessKeyId')
accessKeySecret = responseCreateAccessKey.get('AccessKey').get('SecretAccessKey')
```

Hence, I can use the iam_client to create access credentials for other users (given that the my_profile AWS profile holds creds for an admin IAM user)

Now, with the newly created credentials above, I want to create a new IAM user. The below are the things I have tried to achieve this:

*Attempt 1*

```
temp_session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=accessKeyId,aws_secret_access_key=accessKeySecret,region_name='ap-southeast-1')
temp_iam_client = temp_session.client('iam')
responseCreateUser = temp_iam_client.create_user(UserName='my-new-user')
```

*Attempt 2*

```
temp_iam_client = boto3.client('iam',aws_access_key_id=accessKeyId,aws_secret_access_key=accessKeySecret,region_name='ap-southeast-1')
responseCreateUser = temp_iam_client.create_user(UserName='my-new-user')
```

*Attempt 3*

```
temp_session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id=accessKeyId,aws_secret_access_key=accessKeySecret,region_name='ap-southeast-1')
temp_iam_client = temp_session.client('iam')
responseCreateUser = temp_iam_client.create_user(UserName='my-new-user')
```

*Attempt 4* (as also suggested in one of the answers below)

```
temp_session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id=accessKeyId,aws_secret_access_key=accessKeySecret,region_name='ap-southeast-1')
temp_iam_client = temp_session.client('iam')
time.sleep(5)
responseCreateUser = temp_iam_client.create_user(UserName='my-new-user')
```

**Each one of the above fails with the following error**

> An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the CreateUser operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.

Is there something that I am missing here?
All I want to do is create create a new user with the (as shown above) newly generated access credentials (accesskey and access secret).
It's ok if I get an `AccessDenied`exception. I am expecting that for the users that do not have the right privileges. But the `InvalidClientTokenId` exception is something I don't understand why am I even getting it.

Also, if it helps, I am trying to do this (creation of access key and secret and then using it to create a new user) in an iterative loop for over a 100 users.
(The loop of course handles cases where access keys for the currently being processed user is already maxed out etc.)
So say for example, if I try doing the above user creation action, from the ipython console, individually for the user say, `existing-test-user`, alone, then I get the proper `AccessDenied` exception. However, when the loop reaches that user name (after iterating over the initial few users for example) then I get the `InvalidClientTokenId` exception.

On an additional note was going through [this](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html) the `get_credentials()` section and I'm just wondering if it has anything to do with credentials caching ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS IAM APIs employ an eventually consistent model, so delays happen during updates to IAM resources (such as creating access keys). That means that even if the function call to create an AWS Access Key succeeds, it does not necessarily mean that the AWS Access Key has completed its creation on the AWS Servers immediately.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_general.html#troubleshoot_general_eventual-consistency

#### New Answer

Using [backoff](https://github.com/litl/backoff), we can set a retry policy for the creation of IAM users using newly created AWS access keys whilst having a timeout:

```
import boto3
import botocore
import backoff


@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo, botocore.exceptions.ClientError, max_time=30)
def create_user(access_key_id, access_key_secret, username):
    temp_session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key=access_key_secret,region_name='ap-southeast-1')
    temp_iam_client = temp_session.client('iam')
    temp_iam_client.create_user(UserName=username)


session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='default')
iam_client = session.client('iam')

response_access_key = iam_client.create_access_key(UserName='user')
access_key_id = response_access_key.get('AccessKey').get('AccessKeyId')
access_key_secret = response_access_key.get('AccessKey').get('SecretAccessKey')
create_user(access_key_id, access_key_secret, 'my-new-user')
```

#### Old Answer

Adding a sleep just after creation of the AWS access key is a workaround.

```
import boto3
import time
session1 = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='my_profile')
iam_client = session1.client('iam')

responseCreateAccessKey = iam_client.create_access_key(UserName=user)
accessKeyId = responseCreateAccessKey.get('AccessKey').get('AccessKeyId')
accessKeySecret = responseCreateAccessKey.get('AccessKey').get('SecretAccessKey')

time.sleep(10)
temp_session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=accessKeyId,aws_secret_access_key=accessKeySecret,region_name='ap-southeast-1')
temp_iam_client = temp_session.client('iam')
responseCreateUser = temp_iam_client.create_user(UserName='my-new-user')
```

Comment: I kinda guessed that and already tried it too, albeit with `sleep(5)` in my case. Apologies for not updating that as an attempt and thanks for pointing this out. However, this too did not seem to work, giving the same exception, at least with 5 seconds of sleep. Let me try with 10 too just to be sure.

Comment: i did try it with sleep(5) too and it failed for me, the time taken might vary and may sometimes be longer than 10 (i know its cringy)

Comment: Hmmm, any other workaround for this? Like perhaps an AWS API that can be leveraged to check if the resource has actually been created on the server or not. If there's something of that sort, we can retry until it's done. What say ?

Comment: The https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_general.html#troubleshoot_general_eventual-consistency doesn't talk much about how to handle the delays. It pushes the onus of it on the developer.

Comment: A dirty solution could be to look out for that exception and retry a fixed `n` number of times. If that succeeds well and good, else just drop that request and move on.

Comment: i've updated the answer with the exponential backoff decorator, not pretty but an easier solution